# Found an example for solving via quadratic formula in a book where I am wondering if this is correct

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

As a refresher, I was skimming through a free Calculus online textbook "MOOCULUS massive open online calculus" (https://mooculus.osu.edu/handouts) and stumbled upon the following example solving a quadratic equation via the quadratic formula:

[image]

Is the step where they get rid of the `-10` in the denominator correct? I am wondering because `sqrt(81)/10` is `!= sqrt(8.1)` for example.

Comment: They divided $20$ by $100$, and got $0.2$, which they wrote as $.2$. You may not have noticed the decimal point. It is correct.

Comment: @AndréNicolas why can you just say that $\dfrac{\sqrt{a+b}}{c}=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{c}+\dfrac{\sqrt{b}}{c}$? That is what I see in the solution

Comment: @JChau, square both sides, and see for yourself!  (You can get rid of all the $c$ denominators first.)

Comment: @SammyBlack I have been taught that $\sqrt{a+b} \neq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$. So by saying $\dfrac{\sqrt{a+b}}{c}=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}}{c}+\dfrac{\sqrt{b}}{c}$, it implies that $\dfrac{\sqrt{a+b}}{c}=\dfrac{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}{c}$, which means that $\sqrt{a+b}=\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}$. That is not true. So, if André is right, where is my mistake?

Comment: You are correct that square roots don't distribute over sums, but I don't see how anything that @AndréNicolas wrote suggests that.

Comment: @SammyBlack I actually just realized that I can say that $\dfrac{\sqrt{30^2+20(60-h)}}{-10}=\dfrac{\sqrt{30^2+20(60-h)}}{\sqrt{100}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{30^2+20(60-h)}}{\sqrt{100}}=\sqrt{3^2+.2(60-h)}$. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct.
$$t=\dfrac{-30\pm \sqrt{30^2-4(-5)(60-h)}}{2(-5)}$$
$$t=\dfrac{-30\pm \sqrt{900+20(60-h)}}{-10}$$
$$t=\dfrac{-30\pm \sqrt{900+1200-20h}}{-10}$$
$$t=\dfrac{-30\pm \sqrt{2100-20h}}{-10}$$
$$t=\dfrac{-30}{-10}\pm \dfrac{\sqrt{2100-20h}}{-10}$$
$$t=3 \mp \dfrac{\sqrt{2100-20h}}{10}$$
$$t=3 \mp \dfrac{\sqrt{2100-20h}}{\sqrt{100}}$$
$$t= 3 \mp \sqrt{\dfrac{2100-20h}{100}}$$
$$\displaystyle \large \boxed{t= 3\mp \sqrt{21-0.2h}}$$
I hope this post helped you.

Comment: Oh of cause. I was blind. Thanks!